# Create a database using code-first migrations: What is the order of operations between db.Initialize(...) and db.Create()?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

So let's say I have a reference to a `System.Data.Entity.Database` like

```
Database db = context.Database;
```

and I want to

- Create the database from scratch if it doesn't exist
- Update it if it does exist (sync it with the migration scripts)

directly from C# land (not Package Manager Console).

I have

```
 if(!db.Exists())
 {
    db.Create();
 }
```

to begin with. But I'm not sure when/if I need to use `db.Initialize`. How exactly is that different from `db.Create`? Can someone explain?

Further, when I look at [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database_methods(v=vs.113).aspx) it says about `Create` that

> Note that calling this method before the database initialization
>   strategy has run will disable executing that strategy.

What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

There are four different database initialization strategies:(http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx)

- `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`
- `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`
- `DropCreateDatabaseAlways`
- `Custom DB Initializer`

You can set strategy by:

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyContext>());
```

This strategy is run automatically first time you will trigger any sql command to your DB or during call of `Initialize` method. So you don't need to call it, it will be called anyway.

But if you call `Create` method, it means that you want to just create new DB and ignore your initialization strategy.